# When to use removeEditorPanel()

Tags: block-editor

I'd like to remove the Discussion Panel in the post editor sidebar with `removeEditorPanel()`.

I'm trying to do the following:

```js
const { removeEditorPanel } = wp.data.dispatch( 'core/edit-post' )
removeEditorPanel( 'discussion-panel' )
```

However, I get an error that `removeEditorPanel` is undefined because, I assume, `core/edit-post` hasn't loaded yet. Is there an event or hook that I can use to know that the post editor is loaded?

As a workaround, I'm using an interval to check that `window.wp` exists and a `querySelector()` to check for `.edit-post-sidebar`, but that just feels janky.

Comment: How are you enqueueing your JavaScript? Can you add that code as well?

Comment: @Welcher I'm using create-guten-block, which enqueues with
```wp_enqueue_script(
  'orthoscan_blocks-js',
  plugins_url( '/dist/blocks.build.js', dirname( __FILE__ ) ),array( 'wp-blocks', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-editor' ),
  true
 );```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to how you've destructured it out. I believe dispatch works as a realtime "action". So you need call `dispatch()` when you want to remove the panel.

Try this:

```
const { dispatch } = wp.data;
dispatch( 'core/edit-post' ).removeEditorPanel( 'discussion-panel' )
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that still throws the same error. `wp.data.dispatch('core/edit-post')` and `removeEditorPanel` are both undefined. I think the problem is I'm calling dispatch too early, but I'm not sure how to know when to call it (outside of `registerBlockType`, because I want to remove the panel irrespective of the blocks I register).